# Removing multiple indexes from array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I am trying to write a function that takes 3 arguments and then return a string after removing the given indexes. Here is my code:

```
    var name = {};
    function strCut(arg1, arg2, arg3){
    if(arg1 === 'Jordi')
    arg1.splice(0, 1) && arg1.splice(4,1)
    return arg1
    }
    strCut('Jordi', 0, 4)
```

//I am trying to splice the "J" and the "i"
to return an array of name = ord

Comment: Title suggests array but no array shown in code. Please clarify this is for string or array?

Comment: well the issue will be when you splice it, the index of 4 will now be one less..... And splice is not a method on strings.

Comment: Instead of writing your own you can just use slice. The equivalent would be 'Jordi'.slice(1,4)

Comment: you can not use splice for strings. you can create new string by concatenating the part of string you are going to select.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/83ejrsda/1/

Comment: thanks everyone. I'm a really new at JS (clearly). I really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this function:

```js
function strCut(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  if (arg1 === 'Jordi') {
    var temp = arg1.split("");
    delete temp[arg2]
    delete temp[arg3]
  }
  //  return temp.join("") if you want to return a string.
  return temp.join("").split("");
}
console.log(strCut('Jordi', 0, 4))
```

Look into [Join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and Split [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: `delete` on array won't change it's length and will leave `undefined` in the hole

Comment: We're returning a string. Why care about array length?

Comment: @charlietfl yes, but one: not using the array. two: join cleans it up.

Comment: @epascarello OK...didn't know join() skips holes. Never would have approached it this way myself

Comment: @charlietfl not really, but when you join it with `''` it does not make any difference

Answer (score 1):

- I think you mean a `String` not `Array`? If you need to convert a `String` to `Array` you can use `str.split('');`
- Also I think your function should use `arg2` and `arg3` instead of constant 0 and 4?
- You cannot concatenate strings or arrays using `&&` if that is what you intend, you should use the `+` operator for strings and `.concat` or `... (spread operator)` for arrays.
- The issue is that when you remove one index, the other one gets decreased by one, an easy solution for that is to remove the larger index first.
- Here is your code if it is a String:

> ```
> var name = {};
> function strCut(str, firstIndex, secondIndex){
>   var largerIndex = Math.max(firstIndex, secondIndex);
>   var smallerIndex = Math.min(firstIndex, secondIndex);
>   str = str.slice(0, largerIndex) + str.slice(largerIndex + 1); //Removing the larger index
>   str = str.slice(0, smallerIndex) + str.slice(smallerIndex + 1); //Removing the smaller index
>   return str;
> }
> strCut('Jordi', 0, 4);
> ```

- Here is your code if it is an Array:

> ```
> var name = {};
> function strCut(str, firstIndex, secondIndex){
>   var largerIndex = Math.max(firstIndex, secondIndex);
>   var smallerIndex = Math.min(firstIndex, secondIndex);
>   str = str.slice(0, largerIndex).concat(str.slice(largerIndex + 1)); //Removing the larger index
>   str = str.slice(0, smallerIndex).concat(str.slice(smallerIndex + 1)); //Removing the smaller index
>   return str;
> }
> strCut('Jordi'.split(''), 0, 4); //The string gets passed as an array this way
> ```